# Mustache.js Javascript error when rendering variable

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have

```
var view = {
     firstName: 'John',
     lastName: 'Doe'
};

var output = Mustache.render("{{firstName}} {{lastName}}", view);
```

This gives an error

```
'undefined is not a function (evaluating 'c.attr("partial")')'
```

Comment: Is that really *all* you have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hv6cD/ ... not the issue. You have other code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/janl/mustache.js this is pretty much the same as their most basic example:

```
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function () {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

var output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to start back over in the docs. Are the relevant files/source-code being included correctly? Console errors? Using a conflicting system?

As written your code seems fine, so the problem is just "somewhere else" it seems.

Comment: I have added  a reference to mustache.js in the script. Is there any other important file that I'm missing